# What is the Laplace transform of $d/dt(f * g)$ in terms of $F(s)$ and $G(s)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm not exactly sure as where to start.

We know that the Laplace transform of $h(t) =$ the Laplace transform of $(f * g) = F(s)G(s)$, where $h(t) = (f * g) = \int_{0}^t f(t-T)g(T)\,dT$.

Thus, I was thinking of finding the derivative of $h(t)$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus, and then $d/dt(f*g)=f(0)g(t)$ hence Laplace transform of $(f(0)g(t)) = ?$

But that doesn't make sense.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: The Laplace Transform of the derivative $h'$ is $sH-h(0)$, according to Wikipedia. So that should be $sF(s)G(s)-(f*g)(0)$.

Comment: Using [differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign): ${d(f*g)\over dt}=f(0)g(t)+\int_0^t f'(t-T)g(T)dT$, not $f(0)g(t)$.

Comment: Also note that the Laplace transform of this is $sF(s)G(s)$, agreeing with @ThomasAndrews comment since $(f*g)(0)=0$ (as it is an integral from 0 to 0).

Comment: You are misapplying FTC if you get $d/dt(f*g)=f(0)g(t)$.